# Why does this not work when the load average exceeds 1?

Tags: bash, bash-script

I have been testing [this script](https://github.com/AsheeshR/Bash-Scripts/blob/master/notify-highload.sh) and its behavior has been odd. The script should generate notifications whenever the load average exceeds a specified limit.

Whenever I pass a CPU_LOAD_LMT >=60, no notification is generated whenever the load average exceeds 2 * 0.6 or 1.20 (2 since my system has 2 cores, explained below). There doesnt seem to be anything wrong with the script since notifications **are** generated uptill I pass 50.

The CPU_LOAD_LMT is multiplied with number of cores (`nprocs`) and is then compared to the 100 * loadaverage.

Here is the relevant portion of the code.

```
   list=`cat /proc/loadavg`
   set -- $list

   load=$CPU_LOAD_TIME #Extract required cpu load        
   load=`echo "scale=2; $load * 100" | bc` #Convert to integer
   load=`printf "%.0f" $load` #Remove decimal digits

    highload=$((`nproc`*$CPU_LOAD_LMT)) #Calculate high load threshold based on number of cores

    if test $load -ge $highload
    then

        if [ "YES" == $AUDIO ] 
        then
             paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg &
        fi

        #Generates visual notification
        if [ "YES" == $GRAPHICAL ]
        then
            notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/default.kde4/128x128/devices/cpu.png "High CPU Load"'!' \
            "The CPU has been hard at work in the past minute." #No support for timeouts. Default is 5 seconds.
        fi
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What's CPU_LOAD_TIME set to?

Comment: Your script doesn't do anything that depends on the load average. Whether there is a notification or not depends solely on the value of `CPU_LOAD_TIME` and `CPU_LOAD_LMT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to @Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93105/why-does-this-not-work-when-the-load-average-exceeds-1#comment140965_93105), I finally saw what went wrong!

In the line, `load=$CPU_LOAD_TIME` my intention was to extract either of `$1`, `$2` or `$3` depending on the value of `CPU_LOAD_TIME` (which would be 1,2 (or 5) or 3 (or 15)) set via command line parameters.

This of course, wasn't happening. While testing initially, I was only checking for high loads mostly over 2.00 load average, so I did not spot this as the script was behaving as intended (generating notifications).

I made [two changes](https://github.com/AsheeshR/Bash-Scripts/commit/5c863c958092f29f6b6933ba7451eab10e6327f3) and now the script is triggering at the correct values (Tested both on increasing and decreasing loads, just to make sure). This is the main change:

```
   case $CPU_LOAD_TIME in
      15)load=$3;;
      5) load=$2;;
      *) load=$1;;
   esac
```

Comment: Suggestion: you can use bash's arrays to avoid the `set` stuff: `loads=($(cat /proc/loadavg )); echo "5=${loads[0]}; 10=${loads[1]}; 15=${loads[2]}"`; you can use a variable for the index: `${loads[$i]}`. Note arrays count from 0, not 1. You could also use `read`: `read -a loads < /proc/loadavg; echo "5=${loads[0]}; 10=${loads[1]}; 15=${loads[2]}"`

Answer (score 0):

This version I've modified slightly seems to work fine. I called it `load.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

CPU_LOAD_TIME=$1
CPU_LOAD_LMT=$2

list=$(cat /proc/loadavg)
set -- $list

load=$CPU_LOAD_TIME #Extract required cpu load
load=$(echo "scale=2; $load * 100" | bc) #Convert to integer
load=$(printf "%.0f" $load) #Remove decimal digits

highload=$((`nproc`*$CPU_LOAD_LMT)) #Calculate high load threshold 
                                    #based on number of cores

printf "LOAD: %s | HLOAD: %s\n" $load $highload
if test $load -ge $highload
then
  echo "ge"
else
  echo "le"
fi
```

#### Example runs

```
$ ./load.bash 10 100
LOAD: 1000 | HLOAD: 400
ge

$ ./load.bash 1 1000
LOAD: 100 | HLOAD: 4000
le
```